# IntelliJ IDEA configuration edit is slow

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA if I select Run -> Edit Configurations... nemu item the panel appears quickly, but I have to wait about 10-15 seconds before I can start to edit the fields. Does anyone know a trick how to speed it up? (I guess there must be a calculation in the background, which could be somehow skipped.) Thank you!

Comment: Try to restart IntelliJ with Cache invalidation

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but unfortunately did not help.

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: Windows 7, 64 bit, English.